# How to compute the IPFS content identifier CID from file content in Python?

Tags: ipfs

In Python, I want to compute the IPFS content identifier from a file.

I need to do it for CIDv0 and CIDv1. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For CIDv0, use https://pypi.org/project/py-ipfs-cid/

```
# pip install py-ipfs-cid
from py_ipfs_cid import compute_cid
cid: str = compute_cid(open("filename.txt").read())
```

For CIDv1, use https://pypi.org/project/ipfs-cid/

```
# pip install ipfs-cid
from ipfs_cid import cid_sha256_hash
mhash_base58_2 = cid_sha256_hash(open("filename.txt").read())
```